# Is It Really Required To Make The Mode in Our Nuxt App Universal When We Use nuxt-password-protect package?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently working on a project that is in SPA mode of Nuxt and I want to add a package called `nuxt-password-protect`. This is for security reasons when opening any environment such as dev and staging. I want to provide a password for every access to my staging or dev links. But I am quite confused if it is really necessary to change the mode to SSR/universal? I already changed my mode and it seems working when I also installed the package. Can someone expound some knowledge with this? I am new to nuxt and Vue.

Comment: is this necessary? or `.htaccess` file is also acceptable?

Comment: Was there any issue to use this package with 'SPA' mode? If yes then can you please consider posting that as well?